# MacOS TeXshop 3.45 icon issue

Tags: texshop

I use TeXshop on my iMac and Macbook Air. I've noticed the new icon for TeXshop. For some reason, the new icon does not show up on directories of `.tex` files (I see the old icon instead). Since my Macbook has a small HD, I deleted whatever I thought was left over from old versions of TeX. Since I did this, `.tex` files have *no icon* (or rather a blank page icon that MacOS assigns to files that have unknown type).

I suspect that this is a mixture of (1) me deleting too much stuff; (2) the new version of TeXshop not correctly linking `.tex` files to the icon. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: This is appears to be rather a problem with your OS, and not with TeX itself. Have a look here on how to set default applications for specific file types: http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-change-the-default-application-to-open-files--mac-51413

Comment: @DG'. Thanks but I don't think it's an OS problem. I think it's a problem with the TeXshop front end. I know how to change the application associated with a file type, but the file is already associated with TeXshop. The fact that on my other system, TeXshop files show up with the old icon is another indication to me that something isn't quite right with the package.

Comment: Be it as it may. Your issue has nothing to do with TeX itself. Maybe you should file a bug with the TeXshop developers: http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/bugreports.html

Comment: In my case, I have solved this issue by solving a related issue: Searching .tex documents in Spotlight http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206328/how-to-search-latex-documents-in-spotlight/244791#244791

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is not a TeX question, but a Mac OS question.  The problem has nothing to do with TeXShop *per se*. But it is easily solved. Close all your applications and delete the file `~/Library/Prefences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`

In the Finder you can navigate to `~/Library/Preferences` (use the Go menu) and delete the file `com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`.

If you're comfortable with the Terminal, just `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`

After you've deleted the file, restart your Mac. (Logging out and back in will probably work too.)

An alternative solution, which doesn't involve restarting is to use the following command:

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried (1) renaming the plist file that you mentioned (adding a ".hide" at the end of the filename); and rebooting. That didn't seem to work; I then (2) ran the the lsregister command also (without managing to correct the problem).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Maybe try this: http://furbo.org/2015/01/19/clearing-the-icon-services-cache-in-yosemite/ (untested). Or try a GUI cache cleaning app like [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html).